# .liquid shopify theme causing iOS mobile flickering and page reset

Tags: ios, shopify, shopify-template

My clients theme is 100% custom created before it was handed to me. The theme when loaded on an iOS device is flickering when scrolling and then the page resets. This is happening all through out the website, but again is only happening on iOS devices.

I am wondering if someone could help direct me to where i can begin to search and i do apologize with how vague this is, but i am really just looking for advice on where i can begin to look in the .liquid code to try to fix this. Or is this a JavaScript issue?

Thank you for whatever help you can send my way.

Comment: It's too vague. It can be CSS or JS. Without diving in the code and debugging you won't know. If it's CSS it will be probably some kind of animation, transform or other thing. If it's JS who know what may be.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**:
The issue was with google tag manager script. The previous developer embeded the script snippet incorrectly which had an impact only on the iOS mobile for the site. Very weird and very unusual.

**Advice**:
Be sure to check any 3rd party snippets and embeds that are on a site to make sure they aren't impacting in a negative way.